# Can't install Pyautogui via pip: error code 1

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyautogui

I typed `pip install pyautogui` It gave the error message:

```
Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Crack\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mopggaqx\\pymsgbox\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Crack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vmqzyehf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Crack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mopggaqx\pymsgbox\
```

I tried looking it up and somebody said that I needed to install Pillow first by saying `pip install Pillow`. I tried doing that but something similar came up:

```
Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Crack\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mopggaqx\\pymsgbox\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Crack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vmqzyehf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Crack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mopggaqx\pymsgbox\
```

Comment: Is that the full error message? If not, please post message in its entirety so full context is available.

Comment: The whole idea of a package manager is that you don't manually have to install other packages first. The error seems unrelated to installing Pillow, but to your pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I noticed that at the end of my error message it said

```
Access Denied
```

I ran the command prompt as an Administrator (I don't know why it wasn't already running it as such since I'm logged in as Admin but oh well) and said

```
pip install pyautogui
```

and it worked.